# expo sendPushNotificationsAsync fails silently

Tags: javascript, push-notification, expo

After invoking `sendPushNotificationsAsync` I'm expecting tickets to be returned. Instead I am not getting any tickets returned.

Invoking the following function: (notice `console.log(ticketChunk);` not returning anything). Why am I not getting any tickets returned in this function and without triggering any errors?

```
const sendNotitifications = (messages) => {
    let chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications(messages);
    let tickets = [];

    console.log("chunks: ",chunks);

    (async () => {
        for (let chunk of chunks) {
            try {
                let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
                console.log(ticketChunk);  // <-- returns nothing
                tickets.push(...ticketChunk);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    })();

    console.log("tickets: ",tickets);

    let stackTickets = [];
    for (let [i, ticketChunk] of tickets.entries()) {
        let chunk = chunks[i]
        ticketChunk.forEach((ticket, i) => {
            stackTickets.push({
                stack: chunk[i].data[StackID],
                ticket: ticket
            });
        });
    };

    console.log("stackTickets: ",stackTickets);

    return stackTickets;
};
```

Yields the following:

```
chunks:  [
  [
    {
      to: 'ExponentPushToken[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]',
      sound: 'default',
      body: 'Time for Cheese!',
      data: [Object]
    },
    {
      to: 'ExponentPushToken[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]',
      sound: 'default',
      body: 'Time for Stackeroni!',
      data: [Object]
    }
  ]
]
tickets:  []
stackTickets:  []
```

Answer (score 0):

As weird as it sounds, remove the anonymous function wrapping the for loop.

Do this:

```
    for (let chunk of chunks) {
        try {
            let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
            console.log(ticketChunk);
            tickets.push(...ticketChunk);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

Instead of:

```
(async () => {
    for (let chunk of chunks) {
        try {
            let ticketChunk = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk);
            console.log(ticketChunk);  // <-- returns nothing
            tickets.push(...ticketChunk);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
})();
```

This should work like a charm!